# Monstera brown spot in leaves

Tags: houseplants, diagnosis, leaves, indoors, monstera

I started to see that the leaves of Monstera started to have a brown spots. Here is all the details and photos. Can you please help me identify the reason of the issue and how to fix this and prevent it in the future.

- Plant: [Monstera](https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B083SQR95Y)
- Purchased: 13.Jan.2021
- Watering:

  - 18.Jan.2021: 0,5L water with fertiliser. [Bio fertilising](https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B01EJBB7K2) (5ml in 1L water)
  - 26.Jan.2021: 0,5L water
- Lighting: No direct sunlight
- Location: Germany.
- Temperature: around 20C
- Humidity: around 40%
- Insects: No
- Pot size: 21 cm

| [image] | [image] | [image] | [image] |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] | [image] | [image] |
| [image] | [image] | [image] |  |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plant seems to be in excellent health. Bright glossy leaves, good colour, new shoots healthy and vigorous, it is in the pink of youth and doing well. Occasional spots on leaves likely due to mechanical damage (knock, pinch) when the leaf was young, tender and fragile, nothing to worry about. Keep doing what you are doing and move to new pot when it starts to look unhappy.